# How to split multi-valued comma separated values into individual row in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table `users` having column name `email` where multiple email id are stored as below

```
UserID|Email
---------------
1 | abc@xyz.com,he@xyz.com,ab@xyz.com
2 | ha@xyz.com,aj@xyz.com
```

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to get result in the form

```
abc@xyz.com
he@xyz.com
ab@xyz.com
ha@xyz.com
aj@xyz.com
```

I'm not allowed to change the DB design or create new table.
Can someone please help me figure out if this can be done in MySQL query or not.

Thanks

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? What is maximal amount of emails per value?

Comment: I'm using 5.7.23-log version of MySQL, The maximal limit of emails per value would be 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Email, ',', num), ',', -1) email
FROM users
JOIN ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
       UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) nums
```